# SED change last columnt text

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I would like to ask how to change in last column the letter A to C using sed.
Input for example:

```
HETATM   18  H   UNK     0      12.447  20.851  23.373  0.00  0.00     0.167 HD
HETATM   19  C   UNK     0      11.406  19.947  21.942  0.00  0.00     0.033 A
HETATM   20  C   UNK     0      10.684  20.899  21.181  0.00  0.00     0.030 A    
HETATM   21  C   UNK     0       9.503  20.541  20.507  0.00  0.00     0.019 A    
HETATM   22  C   UNK     0       9.032  19.211  20.545  0.00  0.00     0.032 A    
HETATM   23  C   UNK     0       9.772  18.248  21.264  0.00  0.00     0.019 A    
HETATM   24  C   UNK     0      10.946  18.613  21.948  0.00  0.00     0.030 A    
HETATM   25  C   UNK     0       7.833  18.846  19.889  0.00  0.00     0.253 C    
HETATM   26  O   UNK     0       7.856  18.994  18.642  0.00  0.00    -0.267 OA
```

Output:

```
HETATM   18  H   UNK     0      12.447  20.851  23.373  0.00  0.00     0.167 HD
HETATM   19  C   UNK     0      11.406  19.947  21.942  0.00  0.00     0.033 C
HETATM   20  C   UNK     0      10.684  20.899  21.181  0.00  0.00     0.030 C    
HETATM   21  C   UNK     0       9.503  20.541  20.507  0.00  0.00     0.019 C    
HETATM   22  C   UNK     0       9.032  19.211  20.545  0.00  0.00     0.032 C    
HETATM   23  C   UNK     0       9.772  18.248  21.264  0.00  0.00     0.019 C    
HETATM   24  C   UNK     0      10.946  18.613  21.948  0.00  0.00     0.030 C    
HETATM   25  C   UNK     0       7.833  18.846  19.889  0.00  0.00     0.253 C    
HETATM   26  O   UNK     0       7.856  18.994  18.642  0.00  0.00    -0.267 OA
```

I tried sed like this:

```
sed 's/[A*]$/C/'
```

But the output looks like this:

```
HETATM   26  O   UNK     0       7.856  18.994  18.642  0.00  0.00    -0.267 OC
```

Comment: why sed? awk is easier for such things

Comment: And what is wrong with that output? Do you want "any values in the last column that have an "A" anywhere in them to be changed to just "C" , e.g. any of "A", "AAA", "ABAB", "CCAC" would all turn into just "C"?

Answer (score 2):

Simple **sed** approach:

```
sed 's/\<A[[:space:]]*$/C/' file
```

- `\<` - word boundary (assuming `A` char occurs only as standalone char)
- `[[:space:]]*` - match possible whitespace(s) at the end of the string `$`

---

The output:

```
HETATM   18  H   UNK     0      12.447  20.851  23.373  0.00  0.00     0.167 HD
HETATM   19  C   UNK     0      11.406  19.947  21.942  0.00  0.00     0.033 C
HETATM   20  C   UNK     0      10.684  20.899  21.181  0.00  0.00     0.030 C
HETATM   21  C   UNK     0       9.503  20.541  20.507  0.00  0.00     0.019 C
HETATM   22  C   UNK     0       9.032  19.211  20.545  0.00  0.00     0.032 C
HETATM   23  C   UNK     0       9.772  18.248  21.264  0.00  0.00     0.019 C
HETATM   24  C   UNK     0      10.946  18.613  21.948  0.00  0.00     0.030 C
HETATM   25  C   UNK     0       7.833  18.846  19.889  0.00  0.00     0.253 C    
HETATM   26  O   UNK     0       7.856  18.994  18.642  0.00  0.00    -0.267 OA
```